# Working with dates ,Convert date format to Text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a date column in table

```
Date
2017-04-01
2017-05-01
2017-04-01
```

how can i convert to below

```
Date
01april2017
01may2017
01april2017
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `to_char` with `DDmonthYYYY` forma.

due to format

> `month` will full lower case month name (blank-padded to 9 chars)
>   so you can try to use `replace` function to remove blank-padded.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   DATE TIMESTAMP
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2017-04-01');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2017-05-01');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('2017-04-01');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT replace(to_char(DATE, 'DDmonthYYYY'),' ','')
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/68775/3/0)**:

```
|     replace |
|-------------|
| 01april2017 |
|   01may2017 |
| 01april2017 |
```

If your `Date` type is string, you can try to use `to_date` let it be date type then `to_char`

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'DDmonthYYYY')
FROM T
```